# How filters work? How to make one?

Tags: php

Before you start to hate: I'm not native english speaker and i don't know the exact names of thsese values. Feel free to redirect me to intersting posts/websites.

Start:
Input type: string sent by post method

I'd like how the filters (exactly filver_var) works. Does it remove the 'forbidden' chars from text or can it return false if forbidden chars are used?

How to make my own string filter. I'd like to make filter that alows letters, big letters, numbers and dots.
EDIT: Can I make function that does the same thing?

Comment: Yes you can use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) is the PHP reference on it's implementation and usage of them.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks a lot, but which function should I use? I tried preg_match, but this function returns true if there is at least one char of my charlist. I thought about using preg_filter and later on checking if result string is equal to "" (if the string contained only right chars the result would be blank string), but is it effective?

Answer (score -2):

```
filter_var(var, filtername, options)
```

> Parameter
>
> Description

var: (Required) The variable to filter

filtername: (Optional)

> Specifies the ID or name of the filter to use. Default is
>   FILTER_DEFAULT, which results in no filtering.

options: (Optional)

> Specifies one or more flags/options to use. Check each filter for
>   possible options and flags

Return Value: Returns the filtered data on success, or FALSE on
 failure

```
FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN 258 Validates a boolean 
FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL 274 Validates an e-mail address 
FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT 259 Validates a float 
FILTER_VALIDATE_INT 257 Validates an integer 
FILTER_VALIDATE_IP 275 Validates an IP address 
FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP 272 Validates a regular expression 
FILTER_VALIDATE_URL 273  Validates a URL 
FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL 517 Removes all illegal characters from an e-mail address 
FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED 514 Removes/Encodes special characters 
FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES 521 Apply addslashes() 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT 520 Remove all characters, except digits, +- and optionally .,eE 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT 519 Removes all characters except digits and + - 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS 515 Removes special characters 
FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS     
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING 513 Removes tags/special characters from a string 
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED 513 Alias of FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING 
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL 518 Removes all illegal character from s URL 
FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW 516 Do nothing, optionally strip/encode special characters 
FILTER_CALLBACK 1024 Call a user-defined function to filter data
```